# How do I align my finder scope National Geographic 76/700 EQ

Tags: telescope

Telescope :  National Geographic 76/700 EQ

I tried aiming my telescope at the moon but I just couldn't do it, it was so hard to do, my finder scope isn't helping at all and I watched a bunch of videos saying to use the screws to align the finder scope but the screws on my finder scope don't do anything. Any suggestions?? I really need help tonight is cloudy and I only get like 5 minutes every hour to look at the moon

Answer (score 1):

The moon is generally big enough to not need a finder scope. In general, The easiest way to aim a telescope directly at something is to look parallel to the telescope, right above the edge. If you can just see the object you are aiming at, it should be at least visible in the finder scope (if properly configured, see below). In the case of the moon, try to make just the top half visible when looking parallel to your telescope.

If you are having trouble using a finder scope, it might not be properly aligned. A finder scope has two wires forming a cross. A properly aligned finder scope will have an object in the middle of the telescope's view if it is exactly on the cross of the wires. If this is not the case, the position of the wires can be adjusted using the screws. This is best done at daytime by aiming the telescope at a recognizable landmark (somewhat) nearby, such as a tower.